# Condition on the canonical divisor for Yau Inequality - effective or ample?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, calabi-yau

Let $X$ be a complex, projective, nonsingular variety. We also understand it as a Kähler Manifold. My question now is, when people say $c_1(X) < 0$, what exactly do they mean? Let me elaborate. In [this paper](http://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/~kwchan/MYIneq.pdf), it is said that Yau's inequality

$$ (-1)^n c_1^n \le (-1)^n \frac{2(n+1)}{n} c_2 c_1^{n-2} $$

holds under the condition that $c_1(X) < 0$. I would have thought that this is equivalent to $K_X$ being effective. In the [original paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/74/5/1798.full.pdf), Yau requires $X$ to have **ample** canonical class, however. Now, I am wondering: For the above equality to hold, do I need $K_X$ to be ample or does it suffice for $K_X$ to be effective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read $c_1(X)<0$ as saying that the first Chern class of $T_X$ is *negative*, or the line bundle $K_X$ is *positive*, in the sense of curvature.  But positive line bundles are ample line bundles.  This fact is sometimes called the Kodaira Embedding Theorem.  See for example p. 181 of Griffiths-Harris, Principles of Algebraic Geometry.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of surfaces the inequality is true EDIT: with the only exception of surfaces ruled over a curve of genus  $>1$.  It has beeen proven by Miyaoka [On the Chern numbers of surfaces of general type.
Invent. Math. 42 (1977), 225–237] for surfaces of general type. For surfaces not of general  type it can be proven easily by looking at the classification.

Comment: With the exception of ruled surfaces of genus $g > 1$, I suppose.

Comment: @Jesko: you are right, thank you. I will edit the answer.